# Unresolved dependency updating the module

Tags: 7, views

I'm updating the Views module on a Drupal 7 site, and I'm receiving this message when I update the database.

[image: Requirements problem]

How do I resolve this dependency issue when I need to update the Views module first?

Comment: Hey @Jdrupal, thanks for finding that. However, the question wasn't answered there. I already updated drupal core and downloaded the new views module.

Comment: I don't get it. What's unclear about this message? Why don't you simply update Views?

Comment: So the issue seems to be views won’t update until you do a database update, but you can’t do a database update until you resolve the dependency issue. It’s stuck in a loop...

Comment: I still don't get it. You download the latest Views, unzip it, replace the old, flush cache (maybe run cron), and then this message appears when you want to run database updates?

Comment: Try disabling Views Bulk Operation module and running update.php, then renenable the module and run updates again if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just download a newer version of views and replace in your project.

https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases

If you're using composer just require a newer version.

Then, you should be able to install your drupal.

Best regards 
:)